# Micro frontend routing issue with Next.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am building a micro frontend framework with three Next.js projects (app1, app2, base). `app1` and `app2` are the remote application and `base` is the host application.

app1 `next.config.js`:

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
module.exports = {
  webpack5: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['static.wikia.nocookie.net'],
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options;
    const mfConf = {
      mergeRuntime: true,
      name: 'app1',
      library: {
        type: config.output.libraryTarget,
        name: 'app1',
      },
      filename: 'static/runtime/app1RemoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        './thanatos': './components/thanatos',
      },
    };
    config.cache = false;
    withModuleFederation(config, options, mfConf);
    if (!isServer) {
        config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:3001/_next/';
    }

    return config;
  },

  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config;
  },
};
```

app2 `next.config.js`

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
module.exports = {
  webpack5: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['static.wikia.nocookie.net'],
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options;
    const mfConf = {
      mergeRuntime: true,
      name: 'app2',
      library: {
        type: config.output.libraryTarget,
        name: 'app2',
      },
      filename: 'static/runtime/app2RemoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        './zagreus': './components/zagreus',
      },
    };
    config.cache = false;
    withModuleFederation(config, options, mfConf);
    if (!isServer) {
        config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:3002/_next/';
    }

    return config;
  },

  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config;
  },
};
```

base `next.config.js`

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const path = require('path');

// For SSR, resolve to disk path (or you can use code streaming if you have access)
// in production use the chunks
const ssrRemoteEntry = (app) =>
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? path.join(
        `<remotes-path>/${app}/.next/server/chunks/static/runtime/remoteEntry.js`
      )
    : path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        `../${app}/.next/server/static/runtime/remoteEntry.js`
      );

module.exports = {
  webpack5: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['static.wikia.nocookie.net'],
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options;
    const mfConf = {
      name: 'base',
      library: {
        type: config.output.libraryTarget,
        name: 'base',
      },
      remotes: {
        app1: isServer ? ssrRemoteEntry('app1') : 'app1',
        app2: isServer ? ssrRemoteEntry('app2') : 'app2',
      },
      exposes: {},
    };
    config.cache = false;
    withModuleFederation(config, options, mfConf);

    return config;
  },

  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config;
  },
};
```

base `_document.js`

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <script src="http://localhost:3001/_next/static/runtime/app1RemoteEntry.js" />
        <script src="http://localhost:3002/_next/static/runtime/app2RemoteEntry.js" />
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="Demo for Microfrontends using Module Federation"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

When I run the three applications, on `base` application I can only see the page for `base` but when I click on the other two buttons want to navigate to `app1` and `app2`, the browser shows the blank page.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: any solution onto this?

Answer (score 0):

I may have the solution for you. What you need to do in the next.config.js is add your URLs to your .env file. From there, you tell your base app to navigate to the URL and route.

Here is a sample of what I have done:

```
const { APP1_URL, APP2_URL } = process.env;

module.exports = {
   webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
      config.watchOptions = {
         poll: 1000,
         aggregateTimeout: 300,
      };

      return config;
   },
   output: "standalone",
   async rewrites() {
      return [
         {
            source: "/dashboard",
            destination: "/",
         },
         {
            source: "/app1",
            destination: `${APP1_URL}/app1`,
         },
         {
            source: "/app1/:path*",
            destination: `${APP1_URL}/app1/:path*`,
         },
         {
            source: "/app2",
            destination: `${APP2_URL}/app2`,
         },
         {
            source: "/app2/:path*",
            destination: `${APP2_URL}/app2/:path*`,
         },
      ];
   },
};
```

The tricky part is getting back to your base. Here is a sample for App1's next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
      config.watchOptions = {
         poll: 1000,
         aggregateTimeout: 300,
      };

      return config;
   },
   basePath: "/app1",
   output: "standalone",
   async redirects() {
      return [
         {
            source: "/app1/dashboard",
            destination: "/",
            basePath: false,
            permanent: true,
         },
         {
            source: "/app1/app1",
            destination: "/app1",
            basePath: false,
            permanent: true,
         },
      ];
   },
};
```

Note the webpackDevMiddleware is just for hot refreshing. You don't need it if you don't want.